# Replace characters in one NSString to characters from another NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have an `NSString` like `@"12345"` and another one like `@"##-##-#"`. What is the best way to replace all the `#` characters in `NSString` one by one so it looks like `12-34-5`?

Comment: @nhgrif Iterating through `NSString` with `substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)];` but it requires me to know the exact number of chars which is not convenient.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for NSString???

Comment: @HotLicks yes, sir and what exactly did I miss?

Comment: Well, let's see:  componentsSeparatedByString, rangeOfString, and, of course, good old characterAtIndex.

Comment: @HotLicks But how exactly should I iterate through a string in such a manner? Both string 1 and string 2 could be different with different .length and other stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *original = @"12345";
NSString *toRepl = @"##-##-#";
for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    unichar c = [original characterAtIndex:i];
    for (int j = 0; j < toRepl.length; j++) {
        if([toRepl characterAtIndex:j] == '#'){
            toRepl = [toRepl stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(j, 1) withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", c]];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The return value of `characterAtIndex:` is not `char`, it is `unichar`. BIG difference. And why are you using nested loops? There should only be one loop.

Comment: Code works, I tested it...  Sorry if it's quick and dirty.

Comment: It only works if the original string has characters in a limited range and your code is horribly inefficient.

Comment: I wasn't trying to win an efficiency award... instead of j u s t criticizing, how about showing us the right way?  Of course it could be done a lot faster with some other NSString methods such as replaceFirstOccurenceOfString: withString:

Comment: My comments are more for the OP than you. Just letting them know of potential issues.

Comment: Well for future notice it is more polite to refer to the code rather than the person.  Such as "that code is quite inefficient" instead of "your code is horribly inefficient"... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with a single loop:

```
NSString *pattern = @"##-##-#";
NSString *fillWith = @"12345";

NSMutableString *result = [pattern mutableCopy];
__block NSUInteger index = 0; // Position into fillWith

// Loop over all characters in pattern:
[pattern enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [pattern length])
                            options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                         usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
     if ([substring isEqualToString:@"#"]) {
         if (index < [fillWith length]) {
             // Replace # by the next character from fillWith:
             [result replaceCharactersInRange:substringRange
                                   withString:[fillWith substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(index, 1)]];
             index++;
         } else {
             // Too many #'s in pattern:
             *stop = YES;
         }
     }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misread your question:

Here's a working solution that I tested.

```
NSString *string = @"123456";

NSString *string2 = @"##-##-##";

int i = 0;
do {
    NSRange rangeOfChar = [string2 rangeOfString:@"-"];

    NSLog(@"range %ld %ld",rangeOfChar.location,rangeOfChar.length);

    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",[string substringToIndex:rangeOfChar.location+i],@"-",[string substringFromIndex:rangeOfChar.location+i]];


    string2 = [string2 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:rangeOfChar withString:@""];

    i++;

} while ([string2 rangeOfString:@"-"].location!=NSNotFound);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try on this, single loop and without use of heavy `characterAtIndex`:

```
NSString *pattern = @"##-##-#";
NSString *replace = @"12345";
NSMutableString *result = [pattern mutableCopy];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, [pattern length]);
NSRange resultRange;

NSString *patternCheck = [pattern stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

if ([replace length] == [patternCheck length]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [replace length]; i++) {
        resultRange = [result rangeOfString:@"#" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:searchRange];
        [result replaceCharactersInRange:resultRange withString:[replace substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"pattern:%@ replace:%@ result:%@", pattern, replace, result);
```

will print `pattern:##-##-# replace:12345 result:12-34-5`